# Does spectral radius of a graph increases replacing a subgraph with a graph with more spectral radius?

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, matrices, graph-theory, spectral-radius

Let $G$ be a graph with adjacency matrix $A_G$ and $H$ be an induced subgraph of $G$. Let $H^*$ be a graph with same number of vertices as $H$ such that $\rho(A_H) \leq \rho(A_{H^*})$, where $\rho(A)$ denotes the spectral radius of $A$. Consider the graph $G^*$ by deleting the induced subgraph $H$ and replacing it by $H^*$.

Can we conclude that $\rho(G) \leq \rho(G^*)?$

---

If it is an existing result/theorem can you provide some refernce?

Comment: Possibly a helpful perspective: suppose without loss of generality that $H$ is a graph on vertices $1,\dots,k$ of $G$.  Then we have
$$
A_{G} = \pmatrix{A_H & A_{12}\\ A_{12}^T & A_{22}}, \quad 
A_{G^*} = \pmatrix{A_{H^*} & A_{12}\\ A_{12}^T & A_{22}}.
$$
So, 
$$
A_{G^*} = A_G + \pmatrix{A_{H^*} - A_H & 0\\0 & 0}.
$$
If $A_{G}$ were an arbitrary symmetric matrix, the information about $A_H,A_{H^*}$ would not be enough to conclude that $\rho(A_H) \leq \rho(A_{H^*})$.  If this does hold, we need to exploit the fact that the matrices are non-negative.

Comment: we already know that $\rho(A_H) \leq \rho(A_{H^*})$, then can we conclude that $\rho(G) \leq \rho(G^*)?$ @Omnomnomnom

Comment: Correction: I meant to say "the information about $A_H, A_{H^*}$ would not be enough to conclude that $\rho(A_G) \leq \rho(A_{G^*})$"

Comment: I suspect that the characterization 
$$
\rho(A) = \max_{x > 0}\min_{1 \leq i \leq n} \frac{1}{x_i}\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j = 
\min_{x > 0} \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} \frac{1}{x_i}\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j 
$$
might be useful (cf Horn and Johnson *Matrix Analysis* Cor 8.3.3)

Comment: The result you're looking for easily holds if $H$ can be attained by deleting edges from $H^*$.  However, my guess is that the general result that you are looking for does not hold

Answer (score 3):

This statement does **not** hold.  Here is an example built by taking $H,H^*$ to be [isospectral graphs](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CospectralGraphs.html).  Let $x = (1,1,1,1,1)$.  Take
$$
A_{H} = 
\pmatrix{
     0     &1     &0     &1     &0\\
     1     &0     &1     &0     &0\\
     0     &1     &0     &1     &0\\
     1     &0     &1     &0     &0\\
     0     &0     &0     &0     &0
}, \qquad 
A_{H^*} = 
\pmatrix{
     0   &  1  &   1  &   1   &  1\\
     1  &   0   &  0    & 0  &   0\\
     1   &  0   &  0   &  0   &  0\\
     1  &   0  &   0   &  0  &   0\\
     1   &  0   &  0    & 0  &   0\\
},\\
A_G = \pmatrix{A_H & x\\x^T & 0}, \quad A_{G^*} = \pmatrix{A_{H^*} & x\\ x^T & 0}.
$$
Then we have $2 = \rho(H) \leq \rho(H^*) = 2,$ but $\rho(G) \approx 3.67 > \rho(G^*) \approx 3.37$.